# Disabling click counter function after Timer runs down to zero and alerts "game over"

Tags: javascript, html, button, settimeout

Currently making a basic game. The idea: click as many images in a set time as possible. I wrote some basic code for the timer and click counter. The problem I am having is that after the timer runs to zero and alerts "game over", the player can still click the image and add more to their score.

```js
//Start button hidden after click
      function hideBtn() {
   document.getElementById("toggle").style.visibility="hidden";
     }
      
//Countdown begins, goes to zero, alerts "game over"
      function countdown(secs, elem) {
   var element = document.getElementById(elem);
   element.innerHTML = "Time: " + secs + " seconds";

   secs--;
   var timer = setTimeout('countdown(' + secs + ' ,"' + elem + '")', 1000);

   if (secs <0) {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     alert("Game OVER!");
     //element.innerHTML = "<h1> GAME OVER!</h1>";
    };

  }

//Click counter linked to multiple images
    function clickdone() {
    var hero = document.getElementById("hero");
    var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
    var count = counter.innerHTML;
    count++;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
  }
```

```html
<!--Linking countdown() to html-->
<div class="clock">
 <div id="status"></div>
 <button id="toggle" onclick="countdown(10,'status'), hideBtn()";>START</button>
</div>

<!--Example of one of the clickcounter images being linked to clickdone() and not counting more than one click-->

<div>
  <img id="hero" src="images/img1.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;"
        onclick="clickdone(); this.onclick=null;"/>
</div>

<!--click counter to html-->
<div class="statPanel">
  <span id="counter">0</span>
</div>
```

I am looking for some help linking the countdown() and clickdone() so that when the timer/countdown() hits zero and alerts "game over", the clickdone() becomes inactive but will still show the total clicks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do might be to add a flag for the game being over.

Just add a boolean for game over that is initially false and set it to true when the game is over. Then just check if the boolean is true before allowing more clicks.

Answer (score 1):

When `secs` goes below 0, you can nullify the `onclick` attribute of `img#hero` around the same time that you clear the timer and display the game over message.

```
if (secs < 0) {
  document.getElementById('hero').onclick = null; // <---new code
  clearTimeout(timer);
  alert("Game OVER!");
  //element.innerHTML = "<h1> GAME OVER!</h1>";
};
```

By the way, check out [`WindowTimers.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

> Repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed
>   time delay between each call. Returns an intervalID.

Rather than repeatedly calling `setTimeout` every second, you may find it cleaner to just set an interval, store the returned interval ID and then eventually clear it.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Use the `<element>.addEventListener("click", myHandler)` and `<element>.removeEventListener("click", myHandler)` to allow/avoid click on `<element>`.

---

It's a little dirty ;)

First of all, no JavaScript in your DOM so your current HTML should be:

```
<div class="clock">
    <div id="status"></div>
    <button id="toggle">START</button>
</div>

<div>
    <img id="hero" src="images/img1.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
</div>

<div class="stat-panel">
    <span id="counter">0</span>
</div>
```

There are 4 areas implicated in your request:

- A button start.
- An image.
- A countdown.
- A counter.

So select each Node.

```
// Prepare your elements
var timer = document.getElementById("timer"),
    toggle = document.getElementById("toggle"),
    hero = document.getElementById("hero"),
    counter = document.getElementById("counter");
```

After, we see 7 actions possible:

- Init the game (used when game is reset)
- Start the game
- Set countdown current value -1
- Add a point.
- Allow click on the button.
- Delete click on the button.
- Perform a GameOver

So create functions by intentions:

```
// Prepare your actions
function gameStart (actions) {
  toggle.addEventListener("click", function callee() {
    toggle.style.display = "none";
    toggle.removeEventListener("click",  callee);
    actions();
  });
}

function initGame() {
    timer.innerHTML = "";
    toggle.style.display = "";
}

function gameOver() {
    alert("Game OVER!");
}

function countdown(secs, reachZeroCallback) {
    function removeSecond(next) {
      timer.innerHTML  = "Time: " + secs + " seconds";
      setTimeout(function () {
        secs--;

        if (secs !== 0) {
            next(next);
        } else {
            reachZeroCallback();
        }    
      }, 1000);
    }

      removeSecond(removeSecond);
}

function addPoint() {
  counter.innerHTML = +counter.innerHTML + 1;
  avoidGainPoint();
}

function allowGainPoint() {
  hero.addEventListener("click", addPoint);
}

function avoidGainPoint() {
  hero.removeEventListener("click", addPoint);
}
```

And just use your actions !

```
// Write your Game
gameStart(function () {
    allowGainPoint(avoidGainPoint);
    countdown("10", function () {
        initGame();
        gameOver();
    })
});
```

See this codepen to see game in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdJWYW

**If you proceed by intentions (actions) you will be able to quickly change the behavior of your code.**

Example: If you move `avoidGainPoint` from `addPoint` to `countdown` callback you will able to perform more one click until the countdown reach 0.

---

More advice
 - Not write text into JavaScript code.
 - Not use style but a class to profile all your visual state for a Node element.